# html select - selected value not getting set with logical expression

Tags: html, angular

Trying to load saved setting for dropdown. Tried out the compareWith directive but it not working.

My html tag look like:

```
   <select class="form-control" name="dropdown3" id="dropdown3" [(ngModel)]="address2" (ngModelChange)="onContentChanged()" [compareWith]="compareStates">

          <option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled translate><-- select state --></option>
          <option [ngValue]="state " *ngFor="let state of states">{{state.name + ' (' + ((state.country === '' || state.country === undefined) ? 'USA' : state.country) + ')'}}</option>
      </select>
```

CompareStates method:

```
public compareStates(left: any, right: any): boolean {
    return left && right && left.name === right.name &&
      left.abbrev === right.abbrev && left.country === right.country;
  }
```

json looks like:

```
states = [
    {name: 'Arizona', abbrev: 'AZ', country: 'USA'},
    {name: 'California', abbrev: 'CA', country: ''},
    {name: 'Colorado', abbrev: 'CO', country: 'USA'},
    {name: 'New York', abbrev: 'NY', country: 'USA'},
    {name: 'Pennsylvania', abbrev: 'PA', country: ''},
  ];
```

If I remove the binary operation which is {{state.name + ' (' + ((state.country === '' || state.country === undefined) ? 'USA' : state.country) + ')'}} it works fine.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If I remove the logical expression & make simply {{state.name}} then it works.

Comment: work for me (I remove the `(ngModelChange)="onContentChanged()"`, see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b645z4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: What does `onContentChanged` do?

Comment: this sets dirtFlag which enables save button

Answer (score 1):

You can have separate carrot for `state.country`

```
<option [ngValue]="state " *ngFor="let state of states">{{state.name}} ({{ state.country || 'USA' }})</option>
```